# Concatenation of values inside repeat nodeset using comma

Tags: xml, orbeon, xforms

I have a repeat nodeset which will print all the values inside the nodeset.

I need to print it comma separated like:

```
one,two,three
```

But if I try to concatenate ',' inside the repeat, I am getting the display as:

```
one,two,three,
```

I need to remove the comma at the end of the value.

Comment: Please provide sample code of how you are doing it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`choose()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xforms-20091020/#fn-choose) in your `output`.

For example, if you had this data model:

```
<xf:model>
    <xf:instance>
        <data>
            <foo>one</foo>
            <foo>two</foo>
            <foo>three</foo>
        </data>
    </xf:instance>
</xf:model>
```

and this `xf:output`:

```
<div>
    <xf:repeat nodeset="foo">
        <xf:output value="choose(following-sibling::foo,concat(.,','),.)"/>
    </xf:repeat>
</div>
```

you would get this output (might need CSS change to display inline):

```
one,two,three
```

Note: In the example, the `xf` prefix is bound to the `http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for answering ....But it is not working for me as i have the already given filtration for avoiding duplicate values to be displayed as 'foo[not(. = following::foo/.)]' inside repeat nodeset....

Comment: @LavanyaG - It still works for me if I add duplicate `foo` elements and change my nodeset to `nodeset="foo[not(. = following::foo)]"`. Can you please edit your question with a nodeset and repeat that duplicates your issue?